# SnakeYaml not using my setters

Tags: java, reflection, snakeyaml

I am trying to parse a YAML file with SnakeYaml in Java and I am struggling to make it build my model objects via the setters. What I understood from the SnakeYaml doc, is that when you use object that follow the JavaBean rules, SnakeYaml uses reflection to find setters and use them to instanciate members.

I shrunk down the code to the following minimalist version, and it still does not work as I would expect:

This is my model object :

```
public class Report {

    private String MainSourceFile;

    public Report() {
        super();
    }

    public String getMainSourceFile() {
        return this.MainSourceFile;
    }

    public void setMainSourceFile(String mainSourceFile) {
        this.MainSourceFile = mainSourceFile;
    }
}
```

This is the code that parses the YAML file :

```
Constructor constructor = new Constructor(Report.class);

Yaml yaml = new Yaml(constructor);
Report report = null;

try (InputStream str = new FileInputStream(file);) {
    report = (Report) yaml.load(str);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    throw new ParsingErrorException( String.format("Error while reading export file %s : file not found", file.getAbsolutePath()), e);
} catch (YAMLException e) {
    throw new ParsingErrorException(String.format("Error while parsing export file %s", file.getAbsolutePath()), e);
} catch (IOException e1) {
    Activator.logWarning(String.format("Error while closing file %s", file.getAbsolutePath()));
}
```

And this is the YAML file :

```
---
MainSourceFile:  /home/user/workspace/project/ex.c
```

The following error is thrown

```
Unable to find property 'MainSourceFile' on class: fr.xxx.xxx.model.Report
 in 'reader', line 2, column 18:
    MainSourceFile:  /home/user/workspace/project/ex.c
                     ^

    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.constructJavaBean2ndStep(Constructor.java:268)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.construct(Constructor.java:149)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructYamlObject.construct(Constructor.java:308)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObjectNoCheck(BaseConstructor.java:207)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:196)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructDocument(BaseConstructor.java:161)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:147)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:524)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:452)
    at fr.xxx.xxx.ErrorParser.parseFixesExportFile(ErrorParser.java:116)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: Unable to find property 'MainSourceFile' on class: fr.xxx.xxx.model.Report
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.introspector.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:189)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.introspector.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:178)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.TypeDescription.discoverProperty(TypeDescription.java:240)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.TypeDescription.getProperty(TypeDescription.java:251)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.constructJavaBean2ndStep(Constructor.java:210)
    ... 33 more
```

If I declare the `MainSourceFile` member as `public`, the parsing works (that's why it begins with an upper case). But I'd prefer not to let it `public` and furthermore, I would like to use the setter.
I don't understand the reason why it does not use the setter : my `Report` class seems a legit JavaBean to me.

Is there anything else that I am missing?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I am stuck with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

MainSourceFile should be mainSourceFile.

Comment: this is because bean properties start with a lowercase.